# How to remove paints into surfaceview in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Here I need to remove paints.I did paints using surfaceview.inside erase button  I use below code. Now when I click erase button the drawn paints all erased.But now again draw means paints not visible.please any one help me.

```
  public void onClick(View view){
    if(view==erasebtn)
           {
               if (!currentDrawingPath.isEmpty()) {
       currentPaint .setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        action=true;
    }
             }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely erase all drawing you have to fill it with the "empty" color.

Assuming you have a canvas in which you draw:

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
```

If you have drawn lines etc in a `Canvas` where you just add your drawings all the time then you need to create a way to restore an older version of that. Changing the `Paint` you have used to draw things will not change the things you have already drawn. It just affects how any future drawing is done.

There are several possibilities to do that e.g. the following should work:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, null);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bitmap.getByteCount());

//save the state
bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);

// draw something
canvas.drawLine();

// restore the state
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer):
```

That way you could go back 1 state. If you need to undo more steps think about saving Bitmaps to disk since it will consume quite a lot of memory otherwise.

Another possibility is to save all those steps you have drawn numerically in a list (like a vector graphic) in a way that you can redraw the full image up to a certain point - then you can just undo drawing by drawing just the first part of your list to a fresh image.

Edit: Would it work if you add this to the code and use it instead of `undo()`?

```
// add me to the code that has undo()
public void undoAll (){  
  final int length = currentStackLength();  
  for (int i = lenght - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    final DrawingPath undoCommand = currentStack.get(  i  );  
    currentStack.remove( i );
    undoCommand.undo();  
    redoStack.add( undoCommand );  
  }
}
```

Comment: thkyou for your response.but i am not using bitmap.i am using like this  example.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720432/how-to-erase-paints-on-drawingsurface-in-android

Comment: try{
             mBitmap.eraseColor(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT);
     Canvas Canvas=new Canvas(mBitmap);
              action=true;
               myview.onDraw(Canvas);
                
                }catch(IllegalStateException ie){
                 ie.printStackTrace();}i am using like this now erase function working but how to undo i am not getting.

Comment: I see, so DrawingSurface is that http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/11/drawing-with-canvas-in-android-undoredo.html custom class? It is implemented in the vector drawing approach and if you have a look at the code in that example it has an `undo()` and `redo()`

Comment: i tried like undo,redo as erase.but i am  not getting erase.   and a am taken anthoer example here i taken myview in this using bitmap i am getting erase but here undo is not working

Comment: I've added an `undoAll()` method that should work. If not could you please explain in more details (with images maybe) what exactly you get and what you want? It's not that clear to me.